# Can you tell me why my site is scrolling horizontally?

Tags: css

I am working on a new site, and I just noticed it is scrolling horizontally just a bit, which seems annoying. I have body set to 100vh and there are no other references to any width being more than 100%. I can't seem to figure this out on my own. Can you take a look in developer tools: Click on [Oli's Deals](https://olisdeals.com) and give me some pointers? if you do notice anything! Thank you!

I have removed any padding that might have been causing this, but no change is noticed.

Comment: link is not working

Comment: my bad! maybe I should get oilsdeals,.com and point it to olisdeals.com?!

Comment: works for me. It is because of the vertical scroller showing.

Comment: hmm.  That confuses me. The vertical scroll is showing on SO and I don't have any horizontal scroll bar

Comment: Remove the `width: 100vw;` on `#main-wrapper` and `body`. It's totally useless anyway.

Comment: fyi: use `box-sizing: border-box` on every element `* { ... }` to not calculate padding and margin from the width. (looking at the header). Also you can use `calc()`, an example: `width: calc(100vh - 2px)`

Comment: Just for kicks, I just bought oilsdeals.com and it ppoints to olisdeals.com now

Comment: Thanks @Sysix - duly noted! Update: calc() broke the header but border-box did not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have **nested elements with vw**, and it is causing more width than the normal view port.

For solve this you need to change the width properties from **100vw to 100%**.

In your particular case, change the **body** width: 100% and the **#main-wrapper** to width: 100%

Comment: This works - taking main-wrapper down to 100% did the trick!  and is not a band-aid!

Answer (score 1):

You have set the with to be 100vh. Try setting it to 100% everywhere you have width set. I've set it to 100% in body and header and it fixed it. Don't forget to fix all the weird widths you might have set, like 99% width in the header.

Answer (score 0):

Because of scroll-bar on the right side.

If you want test them. Set `overflow-y: hidden` on your `body` tag.

If you want to remove horizontal scroll just set `overflow-x: hidden` to your `body` tag.

Comment: removing the horizontal scroll is not a fix for this.

Comment: seems like a band-aid but it works!  Thanks

Comment: @richardwhitney Try Blaž Mrak and Erick Santiago's answer. I think these answers are better than mine!

Comment: yes, but yours worked too - just not rightly!